# Vertical align is not working in plain text?

Tags: html, css

The below code is working fine except the past is not working as expected in plain text. I'm trying to add vertical-align:top in Email part (last column in the code) but it is not working.. I need help. kindly find below code and let me know what to do!

**Code:**

```
<table style="width:330px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td
        style="text-align:  center;font-size:8pt;border-right:2px solid rgb(211,211,211);"
      >
        <img
          height="15"
          src="/SigEditorHelper/GetEImage?ImgName=LocationPin_Icon.png"
          width="15"
        /><br />
        <span style="font-size:8pt;"
          >P.O.Box 31279<br />
          Jeddah,21497<br />
          Saudi Arabia</span
        >
      </td>
      <td
        style="text-align:  center;font-size:8pt; width:100px;border-right:2px solid rgb(211,211,211);"
      >
        <span style="font-size:8pt;"
          ><img
            height="15"
            src="/SigEditorHelper/GetEImage?ImgName=Phone_Icon.png"
            width="15"
          /><br />
          M (!Mobile!)<br />
          T (!Phone!)</span
        >
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:  center;font-size:9pt; ">
        <img
          height="15"
          src="/SigEditorHelper/GetEImage?ImgName=email_icon.JPG"
          width="15"
        /><br />
        (!Email!)<br />

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try ```valign="top"``` on the html element you want to be aligned vertically on top

Comment: @ashish rawat thanks a lot!!!!!!! finally it is working after reading hundreds of pages and spending 4 hours to know this!! appreciated.

Comment: well this is the html way, this can be done using css also

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you have `vertical-align: top;` anywhere in your code. If you want it just for the email column, you can do inline styles for that `td` element.

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;">....
```

If you want them all to have it, simply use CSS for all `td` elements.

```
td { 
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:330px;">
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td style="width:165px;">
    <img src="/SigEditorHelper/GetEImage?ImgName=100.jpg" />
  </td>
  <td style="width:165px; text-align:  center;">
    <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14pt;">(!DisplayName!)</span
    ><br />
    <span style="color:gray;font-size:12pt;">(!Position!)</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td
    colspan="2"
    style="font-size:10pt;color:black;border-bottom:2px solid rgb(211,211,211);width:330px;"
  >
    Naseej International Trading Company (NITC).<br />
    Saudi Listed Entity,TASI:1213
  </td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:330px;">
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td
    style="text-align:  center;font-size:8pt;border-right:2px solid rgb(211,211,211);"
  >
    <img
      height="15"
      src="/SigEditorHelper/GetEImage?ImgName=LocationPin_Icon.png"
      width="15"
    /><br />
    <span style="font-size:8pt;"
      >P.O.Box 31279<br />
      Jeddah,21497<br />
      Saudi Arabia</span
    >
  </td>
  <td
    style="text-align:  center;font-size:8pt; width:100px;border-right:2px solid rgb(211,211,211);"
  >
    <span style="font-size:8pt;"
      ><img
        height="15"
        src="/SigEditorHelper/GetEImage?ImgName=Phone_Icon.png"
        width="15"
      /><br />
      M (!Mobile!)<br />
      T (!Phone!)</span
    >
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:  center;font-size:9pt; ">
    <img
      height="15"
      src="/SigEditorHelper/GetEImage?ImgName=email_icon.JPG"
      width="15px"
    /><br />
    (!Email!)<br />
    WWW.Nassejco.com
  </td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="text-align:  center;font-size:9pt; line-height: 0; vertical-align:top;">
    <img
      height="15"
      src="/SigEditorHelper/GetEImage?ImgName=email_icon.JPG"
      width="15"
    /><br />
    (!Email!)<br />

  </td>
```

Try this

Comment: Could you add a short explanation of why you're suggesting this?